# Heroku HTTP 503 Response after long process

Tags: java, heroku

I am making a long process after a http call and I receive this error (503) in the Response.

**I need to increase the Dyno's TimeOut, anybody know how?**

Exception

```
[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Comment: Can you show us any code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I can't increase "Dyno's TimeOut" in Heroku. It is one of the famous constraints of all and is strictly set by Heroku as 30 sec. You can see the details here**

My solution was to make back process with Threads, I make a Thread with the long process and responde "running" with the index of the process, and then I check if its complete making requests by 5 seconds (or something like this)

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase "Dyno's TimeOut" in Heroku. It is one of the famous constraints of all and is strictly set by Heroku as 30 sec. You can see the details [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the timeout, but you can keep the connection open by setting a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header. When Heroku's router sees this, it will not close the connection.

Here is an example project that does exactly that and uses Servlet 3.1 to keep the request thread from blocking:
https://github.com/kissaten/slow-service-example

The relevant code is:

```
response.addHeader("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
```

There is also a nice Scala/Play example if you're into that kind of thing:
http://www.jamesward.com/2015/06/02/redirecting-and-chunking-around-herokus-30-second-request-timeout